# Python: Using variables in function call

Tags: python

Looking to use variables defined earlier in the code when calling a function later in the code.

```
variable = 'a'
results = variable_func()
```

The user has the ability to specify 'variable' in my example. Depending on what the choose, the function will be slightly different. Therefore, I want to be to use the variable when I call the function instead of having to use a bunch of different if then statements.

Is this possible?

Comment: Are you looking for something *other* than passing `'a'` as an argument to the function call?

Comment: Or do you want to call a different function depending on what the value of `variable` is?

Comment: Or do you want to call a different function depending upon what `variable` is set to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want to call a different function depending on what `variable` is set to, the normal approach looks like:

```py
functions = {'a': variable_func, 'b': another_variable_func} # etc.

variable = 'a'
results = functions[variable]()
```